# Can anyone explain/show to me how this code gets an input, as well as how this code is vulnerable to an arc injection by buffer overflow?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Can anyone tell me how this code gets an input, as well as how this code is vulnerable to an arc injection by buffer overflow??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Sets Size to 65

```
enum {SIZE = 65};
```

Variable that I'm trying to change

```
int True = 0;
char name[SIZE];
FILE *f;
int i = 0;
```

How does this read from a file?

```
void read(char *s) {
   int c;
   char buffer[SIZE];

   for (;;) 
   {
      c = getchar();
      if ((c == EOF) || (c == '\n')) 
         break;
      buffer[i] = c;
      i++;
   }
   buffer[i] = '\0';

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
      s[i] = buffer[i];
}


int main(void) {
   read(name);

   if (!True) 
     printf("%s: You are a hacker\n", name);
   else
     printf("%s: You are not a hacker\n", name);
```

How can you not use a return value?

```
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Three questions: first, how many characters is the buffer into which you're reading the name? Once you have that answer, the next question is: can you think of something to type that's longer that the answer to the first question? And now, for the final question: what happens when you do? In order to answer that you might need to keep coming up with longer and longer names.

Comment: 1) it's 65 characters before it starts overwriting memory 2) yes. anything over 65 characters. 3) it crashes most of the time, unless you input the correct hex.  I guess a better question is how do I know when I have the correct return address to overwrite?  Do you even overwrite for an arc injection?

Comment: It's traditional to just ask one question per... question. You might want to consider asking your followup question as a new question, linking this one for context.

Comment: how do I link?  I'm new.

Comment: You'd do something like `here's my question, with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452078/can-anyone-explain-show-to-me-how-this-code-gets-an-input-as-well-as-how-this-c) for context.` The square brackets mark the text you want shown for the link, and the parentheses hold the actual link. That will end up looking like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452078/can-anyone-explain-show-to-me-how-this-code-gets-an-input-as-well-as-how-this-c). I can look at your new question to double-check your link as well.

Comment: Just ping me by including `@computerfreaker` in a comment after you post your new question, and I'll take a look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gets an input through 'stdin;.  By default, this would be done by keyboard input.  However, it may also possible to 'pipe' the content of a file into 'stdin' when loading the program on the command line.

This code is vulnerable to an arc injection by buffer overflow.  Specifically, if more than  65 characters are copied into 'name' array, the value of 'True' will be overwritten.  Most likely, this will change the value of 'True' to a non-zero value.  This will reverse the 'if (!True)' and cause the line 'printf("%s: You are a hacker\n", name);' to execute.

Comment: So, you're saying that true is right after name in memory?

Comment: @JamieFalter, Yes that is quite likely. The 'stack' on many systems grows upward.  Hence if two automatic variables are placed on the stack, the first one (True) will have the highest address. Hence if the second variable defined (name) overflows its space, it will often overflow into the first auto variable (True).

Comment: ok, I figured as much.  But, I'm confuse about something.  If you understand what's going on here, that'd be a huge help. So, lets assume the input is a string 65 chars long.  well, it seems that whatever the string is, it's ended with a 0x00, which overwrites whatever is at the end of the string.  Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: so, if the buffer overflows, and the value afterwards is 0x0000000a, the value instead becomes 0x00000000.  Why?

Comment: Nevermind; my question is why don't the hex numbers immediately after name in the stack overwrite when the name overflows?

Comment: @JamieFalter, of course the (hex numbers, or what ever is there) immediately after name in the stack overwrite when the name overflows.  On some systems, you may even overwrite the 'return address' that was placed on the stack prior to calling the function where the overwrite occurred.  This makes it impossible for the function to properly 'return' to its caller.  Again, it depends on the system, and the direction (up or down) of stack growth.

Comment: 0xbffff318: 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00
0xbffff320: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0x96 0x91 0x06 0x40
0xbffff328: 0x48 0xf3 0xff 0xbf 0xd2 0x84 0x04 0x08
This is the memory for the buffer pre overflow, where the input is all A's, or 0x41. 0xbffff318: 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x0a 0x00 0x00 0x00
0xbffff320: 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41
0xbffff328: 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x00 0xd2 0x84 0x04 0x08
And this is the buffer when it is overflowed as far as it will go w/ just A's.  Whats with the 0x0a000000 not changing?

Comment: @JamieFalter, rather than continuing this discussion here, perhaps it would be better to show the above in a new question (where it can be properly formatted with code to replicate before & after, etc.)?

Comment: I agree. hold on a sec.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that can cause buffer overflow

```
  buffer[i] = c;
```

since you are not checking whether `i` is within bounds before that statement.

When that happens, you are most likely going to override the part of stack frame that contains code since there is no other function variable after `buffer`.

I ran the program by piping the contents of a file that contains 100 `A`s in it to the `stdin` of the program. I got the following message, which confirmed my suspicion.

```
>> cat test-121.in | ./test-121
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./test-121 terminated
Aborted
```

I don't see how that could change the value of `True` at all.

BTW, you have:

```
if (!True) 
  printf("%s: You are a hacker\n", name);
else
  printf("%s: You are not a hacker\n", name);
```

did you mean `if (True)`?? You have initialized `True` to `0`.

**Update**

You asked: How can you not use a return value?

Answer: `return` statement is optional for `main`. Here's a section of the description of main from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function.

> (4) The body of the main function does not need to contain the return statement: if control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`

Comment: whoops.  It should be possible, but believe me, I've had the same feeling.